# How do oob silverlight application communicate through windows

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

If I have two windows in an oob application how do I communicate between them?

This is the new feature of silverlight 5 that allows for multiple windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They run in a common application.  Hence they share the same static data.  The scope of communication choices are therefore very large.  Here is an example:-

```
public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
      public MessageEventArgs(object payload)
      {
           Payload = payload;
      }

      public object Payload {get; private set; }
}

public class Messenger
{
    private static readonly Messenger _current = new Messenger();
    public static Messenger Current { get { return _current; } }

    public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageReceived;

    public void Send(object payload)
    {
          if (MessageReceived != null)
               MessageReceived(this, new MessageEventArgs(payload));
    }
}
```

All windows can attach a handler to `Messenger.Current.MessageReceived` (just be sure to detach when the window closes)  and any window can call `Messenger.Current.Send`.

Ok so you wouldn't actually use this code its a bit rubbish, the point is Windows in SL5 are not isolated.  You can create whatever internal application communication mechanism you need.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: MVVM Pattern

Both windows share a reference to the same view-model. Changes made by one are seen by both.

Option 2: Normal references

Window A can how a refernce to Windows B when it creates it.

Option 3: Message Passing

You can have a global event that you subscribe to in the Load event. (Make sure you unsubscribe in the Unload event or you will leak memory!) Windows can post messages to that event which the other windows listen for.